# How to stop an if statement when it's always true?

Tags: javascript

```
if (userArray[0] === 1 ) {
    cardMaker();
    return false;
    }
```

I have an array where I want to call the function cardMaker when the first value is the array is 1.  The problem is my above code keeps calling the function over and over. I tried to return false but doesn't seem to work.  How can I get the function to invoke once when the first value of the array is 1?

Comment: The code you provided does exactly that.

Comment: Your code would not behave the way you describe unless it's contained in an outer loop or something. Can you post more code for context?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var cnt = 1;// put this line out side of your function
if (userArray[0] === 1 && cnt == 1) {
    cardMaker();
    cnt++;
    return false;
}
```